# Is it possible to programmatically disable TalkBack's *explore by touch* option?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

Some applications cannot function properly when TalkBack's *explore by touch* option is active, but permanently disabling it isn't a viable alternative because not having it on would make using a touchscreen much more difficult for a blind person.

Temporarily disabling TalkBack through a short-cut is a decent work-around, but it becomes annoying pretty quickly when the problematic app is used often and for short periods of time, e.g. a braille keyboard.

Therefore I'm looking for a programmatic solution, for example a deamon configurable through a blacklist: whenever an application from the list is in foreground, the daemon disables *explore by touch*, and re-enables it as soon as an application not on the list comes to foreground. Disabling TalkBack tout court would do, too, if *explore by touch* cannot be disabled without restarting TalkBack.

So... does this exist already? If not, how hard would it be to implement it, if at all possible?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question. // If that feature can be addresses via an intent, apps like [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) might be helpful.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for your comment. My question is mainly a about usage: first and foremost I want to know if such a thing exists already, and "tasker" does seem like a good candidate. Anyway, I flagged this question for migration to StackOverflow, as you (implicitly) suggested.

Comment: For programmatic approaches (as in "programming"), that should be the right site. Please check with their `/help/on-topic` for their "quality guidelines" though, you might need some editing after it's migrated (not sure, I'm not that active at SO). At least the `android` tag should be added then ;) Good luck! // Btw: If you're rather looking for "an app that can disable TalkBack automatically based on the app running in foreground", [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) might be a possibility for that.